# Setting up API access for WordPress installation

Tags: api, permissions, security

I'm using civicrm's API to pull country and state data from CiviCRM into a Gravity Forms address pull-down list.  The current webhooks between Gravity Forms and CiviCRM are failing because Gravity Forms uses a text box for state field, which is unstructured and does not match CiviCRM data.

I see setup for the api gives the option to either check permission or not.  Any reason to check permissions for data for public access?

Answer (score 1):

Checking permissions is important if you want the API to respect the access rights you have given to users? If in your setting and requirement it is not important that you can protect the country and state data you could skip the permission check. Are you using the API on the same server or with REST?

Comment: Yes we are using REST. There is no reason to protect country and state data, but I can't get the REST API to work when permissions=0.

Comment: Did you check the wiki https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/REST+interface? If so, does the user have the required AJAX API permission?

Comment: OK, I will create a user key and a site key.  Thanks for your help.